# Servicio de GPS en segundo plano

Tags: android

He realizado un Service para unas coordenadas GPS que este en segundo plano (se supone que los servicios también se ejecutan en segundo plano).

Este es el servicio:

```
public class ServiciosGPS extends Service {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    FirebaseFirestore mfirestorgps;

    String gmidpasosservicios, erroeservicio;

    private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if ( locationResult == null ) {
                return;
            }
            for ( Location location: locationResult.getLocations() ) {
                // grabo la localizacion en la Base de Datos

                Map<String, Object> mapgps = new HashMap<>();
                mapgps.put( "longuitud", location.getLongitude());
                mapgps.put( "latitud", location.getLatitude());
                mfirestorgps.collection( "GPS" ).document( gmidpasosservicios ).update( mapgps );

            }
        }
    };

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient( this );
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval( 4000 );
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval( 2000 );
        locationRequest.setPriority( LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY );
        mfirestorgps = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        //Bundle extrapasos = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        //gmidpasosservicios = extrapasos.getString( ("paseidpasos") );
        gmidpasosservicios = "Gw7C5jK8PascBWC5LY8X";   //lo pongo momentaneamente porque no  me funciona el paso de parametro
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int  flags, int startId) {
        LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest( locationRequest ).build();
        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient( ServiciosGPS.this );
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> locationSettingsResponseTask = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings( locationSettingsRequest );
        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                // Coordenadas satifactorfias
                startlocalizacongps();
            }
        } );
        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Si falla las coordenadas
                erroeservicio = "No hace nada solo si da error. pasa de el";
            }
        } );
        return  START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates( locationCallback );
    }

    private void startlocalizacongps() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates( locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper() );
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Pues bien ahora lo llamo con esta función desde mi *Activity*:

```
Intent intentpasos = new Intent( this, ServiciosGPS.class );
intentpasos.putExtra("paseidpasos", gmidpasos);
//this.startForegroundService(intentpasos);
this.startService( intentpasos );
```

Y lo cierro así:

```
Intent intentpasos = new Intent(PasosActivity.this, ServiciosGPS.class );
intentpasos.putExtra("paseidpasos", gmidpasos);
PasosActivity.this.stopService(intentpasos);
```

1. Pues todo parece bien y funciona hasta que pasa a segundo plano y deja de funcionar, es decir, no envía las coordenadas, cuando vuelve a primer plano vuelve a funcionar.

   También he llamado al servicio con esta otra:

   ```
    this.startForegroundService(intentpasos);
   ```

   Pero aunque parece que funciona bien e incluso en segundo plano, cuando se cierra el servicio da algún fallo mas adelante en la app que no da con la otra llamada.

   ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que funcione en segundo plano con la primera llamada que he puesto?
2. Como veis intento pasarle un parámetro pero en el servicio no se como capturarlo ya que en la línea :

   ```
    Bundle extrapasos = this.getIntent().getExtras();
   ```

   El `getIntent()` enta en rojo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Al pasar a background no has visto si se muestra un error de tipo "SecurityException"?.

Comment: Me sale esto cuando pasa a segundo plano:I/GED: ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@89b9270, this = DecorView@92a3bed[PasosActivity]
D/FA: Application going to the background
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que si tu .APK se compila con un [`targetSdk=28` ( Android 9 ) o mayor, es necesario definir el permiso](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#request-foreground-service-permissions):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

Con respecto a que en el servicio no puedes recibir un parametro, lo correcto es realizarlo en el mètodo `onStartCommand()` de tu servicio:

```
protected void onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   
    Bundle extrapasos = intent.getIntent().getExtras();

}
```

Comment: Le he puesto el permiso y sigue fallando de la misma manera que explique tanto en startForegroundService(intentpasos); como si le pongo startService(intentpasos);, este ultimo no lo hace en segundo plano.. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cuando llamo al servicio con  startService(intentpasos); y despues paso a segundo plano, me he dado cuenta que el servicio se desconecta y pasa a la inactividad.

```
I/System.out: Provider contains=> gps,network
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 172263
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 71543042
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x746c2a3000,api=1)
I/GED: ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, 
oppidx_min 0
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = 
android.view.ViewRootImpl@89b9270, this = DecorView@92a3bed[PasosActivity]
D/FA: Application going to the background
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

¿Porque pasa esto?

Estos son los permisos que tengo en el Manifiest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```